# Problem on normal distribution probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

An investment portfolio contains stocks of a large number of companies. Over the past\ year the rates of return on these corporate stocks followed a normal distribution with-As mean 12.5% and standard deviation 7.4%. Assuming that the rates of return for different companies are independent of each other, select the appropriate statement below.

- A. The probability of a rate of return above 15% for these companies
  is 0.4801, a level of return of 82.59% was exceeded by the top 10% of
  stocks, and the average rate of return over any 4 selected stocks in
  this portfolio has a distribution that is normally distributed with a
  mean of 12.5% and a standard deviation of 3.7%.
- B. The probability of a rate of return above 15% for these companies
  is 0.3669, a level of return of 21.97% was exceeded by the top 10% of
  stocks, and the average rate of return over any 4 selected stocks in
  this portfolio has a distribution that is normally distributed with
  a. mean of 50% and a standard deviation of 14.8%.
- C. The probability of a rate of return above 15% for these companies
  is 0.3669, a level of return of 21.97% was exceeded by the top 10% of
  stocks, and the average rate of return over any 4 selected stocks in
  this portfolio has a distribution that has an unknown form but with a
  mean of 12.5% and a standard deviation of 3.7.4.
- D. The probability of a rate of return above 15% for these companies
  is 0.2709, a level of return of 23.4% was exceeded by the top 10% of
  stocks, and the average rate of return over any 4 selected stocks in
  this portfolio has a distribution that is normally distributed with a
  mean of 12.5% and a standard deviation of 3.7%.

1. E. The probability of a rate of return above 15% for these companies
   is 0.3669, a level of return of 21.97% was exceeded by the top 10%
   of stocks, and the average rate of return over any 4 selected stocks
   in this portfolio has a distribution that is normally distributed
   with a mean of 12.5% and a standard deviation of 3.7%.

Comment: What do you use to evaluate the value of $\Phi(z)$, a table or a calculator?

Comment: online calculator. I have found The probability of a rate of return above 15% for these companies is 0.3669 but rest of the problem I cant understand

Comment: I used an online calculator as well. But [this one](https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx) shows $1-0.632=0.378$. It is a little bit different from the given solution.

Comment: use [this calculator](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573188)

Comment: Yes, the result is indeed another one. What is the part you have problems with?

Comment: a level of return of % was exceeded by the top 10% of stocks, and the average rate of return over any 4 selected stocks in this portfolio has a distribute...... this part

Comment: OK, I´ve tried my best. Feel free to ask, if something is still unclear.

Comment: Can you please help me do this At a certain time of day, customers arrive in a bank randomly at a rate of 1 people per minute, according to a Poisson distribution. find the probability that 2 people arrive in a given minute and 1 person arrives in the next minute

Comment: You should ask a new question and then wait several minutes for a comment/answer.

Comment: I have already asked  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773530/i-have-a-problem-on-finding-probability-of-poisson-distribution)

Comment: I see. Can you add any ideas to your questions?

Comment: I´ve posted some hints there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t write the percentage sign in my calculations.

$\textrm{... a level of return of x% was exceeded by the top 10% of stocks,}$

The equation is $P(X\geq x)=1-P(X\leq x)=0.1$

$$1-\Phi\left(\frac{x-12.5}{7.4} \right)=0.1$$

$$0.9=\Phi\left(\frac{x-12.5}{7.4} \right)$$

$$\Phi\left(0.9\right)^{-1}=\frac{x-12.5}{7.4} $$

$$1.282=\frac{x-12.5}{7.4} $$

$$x=21.9868$$

So the answer is approximately $21.97\%$. The differences in decimal digits are not so important. You can exclude the options $A$ and $D$.

$\textrm{ and the average rate of return over any 4 selected stocks in this portfolio}$  $\textrm{ has a distribution that is normally distributed with a mean of y% and a standard deviation of z%}$

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be n independent, identically and normally distributed random variables as $X_i\sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

And let $\overline X_n=\frac{X_1+ X_2+ ...+ X_n}{n}$. Then the distribution is $\overline X_n\sim \mathcal N\left(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}n\right)$. That means in your case $$\overline X_4\sim \mathcal N\left(12.5, \frac{ 7.4^2}4\right)$$

Therefore the standard deviation of $\overline X_4$ is $\sqrt{\frac{ 7.4^2}4}=\frac{7.4}{2}=3.7$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please help me do this

At a certain time of day, customers arrive in a bank randomly at a rate of 1 people per minute, according to a Poisson distribution. The probability that 2 people arrive in a given minute and 1 person arrives in the next minute